# Logout automatically on token expiration time in blazor web assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a blazor web assembly app. I created login and logout approaches, for logout on token expiration time, I store an expiration date in local storage. but checking this date require a full page load. I want to check that date automatically or when I open a page and redirect to login page if that time passed.

This is my **CustomAuthenticationStateProvider.cs**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(HttpClient httpClient, ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _localStorageService = localStorageService;
    }

    private async Task<bool> TokenExpired()
    {
        bool expire = false;

        var exist = await _localStorageService.ContainKeyAsync(ClientConstantKeys.AppTokenExpireDate);

        if (exist)
        {
            var dateString = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>(ClientConstantKeys.AppTokenExpireDate);
            var date = DateTime.Parse(dateString);

            if (DateTime.Now >= date)
            {
                expire = true;
                await NotifyUserLoggedOut();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            expire = true;
            await NotifyUserLoggedOut();
        }

        return expire;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var token = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>(ClientConstantKeys.AppToken);
        var expired = await TokenExpired();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) || expired)
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }

        var claimsValueTypes = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<Dictionary<string, object>>(ClientConstantKeys.AppClaims);
        var claims = ClaimParser.GetClaims(claimsValueTypes);

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);


        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "jwtAuthType")));
    }

    public void NotifyUserLogIn(List<Claim> claims)
    {
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "jwtAuthType"))));
        base.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }

    public async Task NotifyUserLoggedOut()
    {
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity())));
        await _localStorageService.RemoveItemAsync(ClientConstantKeys.AppToken);
        await _localStorageService.RemoveItemAsync(ClientConstantKeys.AppClaims);
        await _localStorageService.RemoveItemAsync(ClientConstantKeys.AppTokenExpireDate);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
        base.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }
}
```

And this is **App.Razor**

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
              <AccessDenied></AccessDenied>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <PageNotFound></PageNotFound>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

When I click on login or logout everything is ok, but I want check the expiration time automatically.

I try wrapped my whole page with **AuthorizedView** tag, but nothing happen.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @SBU Maybe it's not a good idea but I create a component without any markup and in it's **OnInitializedAsync** method check the token expiration time, if token is invalid call the **NotifyUserLoggedOut** method mentioned above and navigate to login page. I have to add this component to every component that I want to check the token before open it.

Comment: Actually I came up with a similar idea. I am checking token expiration on Filter Pipeline which returns 401. I made a function on MainLayout to handle the errors and sending that function to other components via CascadingParameter. And if the catch state catched 401, I logout the user and redirect to Login.

Comment: @SUB Yes, It seems they are the same idea, I will try it, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used FilterPipeline to check the token expiration time, then I checked the response type on Blazor WASM after each request. Made a function to make the code clean. Here is how:

WebAPI->Filter->JwtTokenValidateAttribute.cs

```
 public class JwtTokenValidateAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            string token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                return;
            }

            var tokenManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICustomTokenManager)) as ICustomTokenManager;
            if(tokenManager != null && !tokenManager.VerifyToken(token))
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

After we make our Attribute, we can call this on controllers like this:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ApiController]
    [JwtTokenValidateAttribute] //here we call the filter pipeline
    public class SupplierCompaniesController : ControllerBase
    {
       //your controller goes here
    }
```

MainLayout.razor:

```
@code{
 public async Task HandleException(Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception.Message.Contains("401"))
        {
            await AuthenticationUseCases.Logout();
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login/Expired", true);
            return;
        }
//If you use AutoWrapper or other packages, you can send messages here based on your response type, don't forget to parse the values. 
    }
}
```

After that we can call HandleErrors in any page that we are sending a request to API, example:

First we need to wrap @body with CascadingValue

```
<CascadingValue Value="this" Name="MainLayout">
     @Body
</CascadingValue>
```

Now we need to go to any Razor Component we are going to send a request to API

```
@code{
[CascadingParameter(Name = "MainLayout")]
public MainLayout MainLayout { get; set; }
async Task HandleException(Exception e) => await MainLayout.HandleException(e);

async Task OnCreateRow(RoleDto role)
    {
        try
        {
            //Your api call goes here
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await MainLayout.HandleException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution may not be the best one, I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @SBU method with the Radzen.DialogService then do this. Hope this helps people who are using Radzen.

```
try{

   }
catch (Exception ex)
   {
      //Send back the Exception as the result   
      DialogService.Close(ex)
   }
```

Then, in your calling method do something like this.

```
var exception = dialogResult as Exception;

if (exception != null && exception.Message.Contains("401"))
{
   await HandleException(exception);
}
else
{

}
```